# CFLAGS="-arch armv7" vs CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch arm64"

Tags: ios, macos, makefile, build, static-libraries

I want to compile a static library that supports both armv7 and arm64.What are the differences between the following two operations?

- `CFLAGS="-arch armv7"  CFLAGS="-arch armv7"` Build the two architectures separately and then use lipo to create a fat static libraries.
- `CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch arm64"` Build static libraries that support both architectures at once.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference. You can examine the libraries produced using the command

```
lipo -detailed_info YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME
```

Both of them should be fat files.

Comment: I happened to find that compiling once was feasible. But in my past cognition, the build is always separate, and some open source projects do the same, such as [FFmpeg-iOS-build-script](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script/blob/master/build-ffmpeg.sh). This makes me very confused, isn't it faster and more convenient to build it once? Or must iOS be built separately?

Comment: There should be not much difference, iOS and macOS behave the same way with fat files